# Not getting any results for Date query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

I am running the following query in my account to get all subscribers that have a departure date in 3 days:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey

FROM [Trip]
WHERE Date_of_Departure = DATEADD(day, +3, GETDATE())
```

However, the query returns 0 records, although a Data Filter with the same logic returns 27 records. What would I need to change in this query so that it can run using Automation Studio on a daily basis and always appends the users that have a departure date in today +3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to handle the time portions of the dates in SFMC Query Activities.

Casting the date column as a `date` will set the time to `00:00`.

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM [Trip]
WHERE Date_of_Departure >= DATEADD(day, 3, cast(GETDATE() as date))
and Date_of_Departure < DATEADD(day, 4, cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

Or less efficiently:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM [Trip]
WHERE cast(Date_of_Departure as date) = DATEADD(day, 3, cast(GETDATE() as date))
```

Answer (score -1):

In a SOQL query you can specify either a particular date or a date literal. A date literal is a fixed expression that represents a relative range of time, such as last month, this week, or next year.

**NEXT_N_DAYS:n**

For the number n provided, starts 12:00:00 of the current day and continues for the next n days.

Example:

```
    List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = NEXT_N_DAYS:3];
System.debug('###'+oppList);
```

[Reference Salesforce Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

Comment: This is not a Sales Cloud question.